# Iphone app browser window - Add value to user agent string

Tags: android, iphone, ios

We are developing an Iphone app and an Android app. It has a browser window in it and it "looks" at a specific URL for content. Now, we would like to add a value to the user agent string. appname/version. (We serve different content depending on device/browser that access the information.) Is that possible?

Any suggestions?

Best,
Jon

Comment: In theory, yes, if the browser provides an API which enables you to add data to the user agent.  In practice, no, since you do not know the browser the user is using.  User agent strings are not good for this purpose.  Every website I visit believes I'm an iOS device (I'm actually an Android user) since so many websites seem to have not heard of Android ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass those values as GET params in the url?

For android:
http://www.somedomain.com/page.html?appName=myAndroidApp&ver=version

For ios:
http://www.somedomain.com/page.html?appName=myIphoneApp&ver=version